# overlapping partitions problem

Tags: partitioning, installation

i have got a new hp g6 laptop and when trying to install ubuntu , i face this problem

Gparted sees the whole hard drive as unallocated disk space
and the output of fdisk -lu is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc13cbdc4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2          409600   159584255    79587328    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3      1208201216  1241939967    16869376    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4       159584256  1250260991   545338368    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda5       159586304   683874303   262144000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6       683876352  1208201215   262162432    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7      1241942016  1250260991     4159488    b  W95 FAT32

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

so is there an easy way to fix the overlapping partitions problem ?

only the disk utility can view the partition layout 
[image]

i also tried the following command

sudo sfdisk -uS -l /dev/sda

and it gives the following

```
Disk /dev/sda: 77825 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      2048    409599     407552   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2        409600 159584255  159174656   7  HPFS/NTFS
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (717,232,27)
/dev/sda3     1208201216 1241939967   33738752   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4     159584256 1250260991 1090676736   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
        start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (717,232,28)
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (1,37,36)
/dev/sda5     159586304 683874303  524288000   7  HPFS/NTFS
        start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (717,200,60)
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (585,116,43)
/dev/sda6     683876352 1208201215  524324864   7  HPFS/NTFS
        start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (585,85,13)
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (455,76,5)
/dev/sda7     1241942016 1250260991    8318976   b  W95 FAT32
        start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (507,208,22)
        end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,254,63) found (1,37,36)
```

so how can i fix those boundaries ?

Comment: Please note that the "Disk Utility" screenshot isn't showing the real partition layout.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand the problem here it is necessary to know how disk partitioning works.
A classic DOS partition table can only contain four entries. To circumvent this restriction while staying compatible, one partition type was defined to be a so-called extended partition which can itself contain additional "logical partitions".

On your drive, there is a "hole" in the extended partition where no *logical* partition is defined. Instead a primary partition overlaps the extended partition and fills that hole exactly. So no *data* is really overlapping, and there is no immediate danger of data loss.

The easiest solution is to delete the offending partition (/dev/sda3) if you don't need it. Afterwards you can try to create a new logical partition at the same position. I recommend using fdisk for this as it doesn't try to format anything, so if you made a backup of your partition table you can simple restore it and try again.

**WARNING**

This is dangerous, and you should have a **full backup** of your drive before doing it.

Comment: if you could provide me with a tutorial about doing this , i will really be grateful..

Comment: To delete the partition, just press d in fdisk and select the right one, then write your changes to disk with w. However if you need a detailed step-by-step tutorial, that's a strong indicator that you're perhaps better off with making a backup and wiping the disk clean.